# Screen Power & Sleep Settings keep reseting on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power

This is a bug I have since a long time on my Win10 computer and never could found a fix.

In the Power & Sleep options, Screen turn off setting is set to 15 minutes. No matter how I try to change that, it always reset to 15 minutes as the defaut setting after the computer restart. This appears to be random though. Sometimes, after a change of this option, the 15 minutes setting is back right after I restart the computer, sometimes it takes 3 or 4 days of use/restart to come back.

What I already tried that doesn't work :

- Going to **additional power settings** and trying to change power plan advanced power settings is of no use. Even if I set everything to never or to 9999 minutes, even the Display and Hard disk turn off time option, it still reset to 15 minutes after a while.
- **Creating a custom power plan**. Strangely enough, this seems to buy me a few days or so, since the 15 minutes takes a bit more time to come back when I do that. But it may just be an impression. Anyway, it still reset to 15 minutes after a while in this newly created power plan.
- **Disabeling screen saver**. I never had and nerver use a screen saver. The problem is that the monitor turns off.
- I read on several forums that it may be related to some applications or services that set this power settings back every time I log to my computer. I tried to find some of the mentionned applications but found none installed except for **Intel Rapid Storage Technology**. I went into the performance tab and disabled Power Management and tought it was fixed, since I had no problem for a while. But it came back to 15 minutes again recently.
- I tried to look for any **BIOS settings** related to power management but could'nt find any. I could have missed something however since I'm not that confident with BIOS options and don't want to try and mess with some parameter I don't understand well. My motherboard is : MSI MPG Z390 GAMING PLUS (MS-7B51).

Please help me if you have any idea on what may cause the problem and how to fix it, beacause I have none left.

Comment: Are you part of a windows domain?

Comment: No I am not. And the PC is only used by me, on an admin account.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, turns out it was Bitdefender automatic optimization. Turned that off, problem is gone.

Comment: this problem has been plaguing me for almost a year, and I could deactivate it in my bitdefender profile. Thank you so much for pointing it out, I would have never thought of that. Now the setting I chose in windows sticks after reboot.